# Lauterbach Difference Hardware - Software - Onchip Breakpoints

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, lauterbach

I have read the Lauterbach documentation and they have mentioned, SW, HW and OC BP.

I know what a SW BP is, it basically inserts a assembly instruction to stop.

OC BP use specific registers and comperators procided by the MCU that is accesed via a JTAG interface.

What is then the difference between HW and OC BP?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Lauterbach documentation, the term *Hardware Breakpoint* used to refer to a breakpoint implemented in the hardware of an In-Circuit Emulator. Such emulators were used in the past to debug processors that did not implement any on-chip debug logic. A bus monitor would observe the address and data buses and would cause the processor to halt when an address comparator found that the breakpoint address was fetched by the processor.

Nowadays, the term *Hardware Breakpoint* is sometimes used instead of *On-chip Breakpoint* with the meaning "not a software breakpoint". The naming in the manual may also be aligned to the naming in the processor manufacturer's documentation, where on-chip breakpoints are sometimes refered to as hardware breakpoints.